# MySQL: Lost connection to MySQL server during query while clearing big table

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I see a lot of questions about "Lost connection to MySQL server during query". But there are no answers for me. I have innodb table with 2.000.000 rows and I want to clear this table with `delete from sometable`. But it fails with exception  `"Lost connection to MySQL server during query"`. I tried to execute it in transaction and wthout (I use **C#**). There are two additonal messages `"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."` and `"Server did not respond within the specified timeout interval."`I tried to increase some timeouts but it didn't help:

```
set innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 20000;
set net_read_timeout = 20000;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: If you want to clear the table `TRUNCATE` is usually faster (as long as you don't need to preserve current auto-increment value). Alternatively, you can DELETE with a LIMIT, and repeat until rows affected = 0 or less than the limit.

Comment: @Uueerdo Ok but why it doesn't work with delete? Yes, I thought about deletion with chunks but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Those look like MySQL settings, the api you are using in C# may have it's own set of timeouts.

Comment: MySqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout and MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout worth to make a try.

Comment: Thanks, MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout works for me.

Comment: You should check the server's error log.  It *should* work.  You might have something else going wrong, like corruption in the table, or a hardware issue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It's my local machine and I saw only errors from me program. I'll check again.

Comment: "server" = mysql server daemon, wherever it may be running, your local machine in this case.  The MySQL error log. Possibly called `/var/log/mysql/$(hostname).err`.